# Перегрузка методов PHP

Tags: php

Создать класс с несколькими конструкторами, вызывать конструкторы в зависимости от переданных параметров

```
<?php
class BaseClass {
    private $data = array();

    function __construct($color) {

    }

    function __construct($color, $name) {

    }

    function __destruct() {
        //$obj = new BaseClass();
    }
}

$obj2 = new BaseClass("dfdfg", "dsdsdssdsddssd");
?>
```

сделать так что бы вызывался тот конструктор, в зависимости от того какие параметры я задаю ( `$obj2 = new BaseClass("dfdfg", "dsdsdssdsddssd");` )

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.overloading.php

Comment: в чем вопрос то?

Comment: не позволяет пхп делать классический `overloading`-мтеодов. Нужно несколько вариантов создания объекта - делайте статические методы, возвращающие объект после нужных манипуляций

Answer (score 2):

Можно и так сделать

```
<?php
class BaseClass {
    private $data = array();

    function __construct($color, $name = null) {
        if (null === $name) {
            $this->construct1($color);
        } else {
            $this->construct2($color, $name);
        }
    }


    private function construct1($color) {

    }

    private function construct2($color, $name) {

    }

    function __destruct() {
        //$obj = new BaseClass();
    }
}

$obj2 = new BaseClass("dfdfg", "dsdsdssdsddssd");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите этот пример на `func_num_args()` и `func_num_args()`, может быть он поможет вам.

```
class Foo {

  public function bar()
  {
    printf("Количество параметров: %d\n", func_num_args());
    $methodName = 'bar' . func_num_args();
    call_user_func_array([$this, $methodName], func_get_args());
  }

  public function bar0()
  {
    printf("Вызван метод без аргументов\n");
  }

  // метод с 1 аргументом
  public function bar1($var1)
  {
    printf("Вызван метод с 1 аргументом: %s\n", $var1);
  }

  // метод с 2 аргументами
  public function bar2($var1, $var2)
  {
    printf("Вызван метод с 2 аргументами: %s, %s\n", $var1, $var2);
  }

}

$f = new Foo;
$f->bar();
$f->bar('1');
$f->bar('1', '2');
```