# Перегрузка метода в PHP

Tags: php

подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сделать перегрузку с помощью метода __call, задача такова: Создать класс с несколькими конструкторами, вызывать конструкторы в зависимости от переданных параметров

вот код

```
<?php
class BaseClass {
    //private $data = array();

       private function construct1($color) {
echo "1234";
    }

    private function construct2($color, $qwerty) {
echo "qwerty";
    }
      private function construct3($color, $qwerty, $name) {
echo "09876";
    }


        public function __call(){
                if (null === $qwerty) {
            $this->construct1($color);
        } elseif (null === $name) {
            $this->construct2();
        }
        else {
            $this->construct3 ($color, $qwerty, $name);
        }

        }

    }


    function __destruct() {
        //$obj = new BaseClass();
    }
}

$obj2 = new BaseClass("234567");
?>
```

Comment: `Создать класс с несколькими конструкторами` - определяйте поведение непосредственно в методе `__construct`, магия `__call` для него не работает.

Comment: а как сделать тогда ниначе, что бы эта магия __call работала? делали уже инын способом все работает но требуют сделать этим методом перегрузку, к сожалению не выходит

Comment: А может проще использовать `__construct(...$params)`? Можно будет передавать в конструктор любое количество параметров

Comment: Вы хотите использовать магический метод __call для создания объекта? Начнём с того что __call работает в контексте объекта и что бы метод __call начал работать, нужно создать объект с использованием обычного конструктора.

Comment: я не использую __call для создания, а для проверки, в нем должно быть условие

Comment: [расскажите, откуда вы там все эту  задачу берете?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/619274/223826) уже по моему третий раз публикуют за последнее время.

Comment: @teran может они куда-то собеседование проходят? ))) ну или студенты какие

Answer (score 4):

У вас какая-то каша. Похоже вы просто не знает о том что аргументам функции можно задавать параметры по умолчанию. В вашем случае код может выглядеть так

```
<?php
class BaseClass {
//private $data = array();

  public function __construct($color, $qwerty = null, $name = null) {
    if ($qwerty === null && $name === null) {
      echo "09876";
    } elseif ($qwerty === null) {
      echo "qwerty";
    } else {
      echo "1234";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: плюсанул, но не могу не заметить, что всех проблем такой подход не решает. Например, если надо иметь два конструктора, один из которых принимает `($color,$qwerty)`, а второй, например, `($color,$name)`

Comment: @rjhdby почему же не решает. Просто вместо "ненужного" параметра передается null. PHP это не С++ - тут перегрузку метода в зависимости от типа параметров не сделаешь. В данном же случае у автора явно каша в голове и в архитектуре.

Comment: Потому, что это не решение, а костыль. Насколько я понял, автор хочет реализацию как, например, в Java

Comment: @rjhdby =) ну а что сложного-то в задаче автора? я привел решение )))

Comment: @Stanislav тут вопрос не про сложность, а про нереализуемость в том виде, в котором он хочет. Человеку привыкшему к той же джаве, по началу, подход PHP видится несколько ущербным. Ну не умеет PHP несколько конструкторов :)

Comment: @rjhdby согласен, именно в том виде я не вижу никаких вариантов решений...

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно создавать объект в зависимости от входных параметров, то есть три более менее правильных пути:

1. см. ответ newman
2. Воспользоваться паттернами [фабричный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) или [строитель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). [Вот тут расписано как реализовывать их на PHP](http://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/Creational/README.html)
3. Передавать в качестве аргумента ассоциативный массив с необходимыми параметрами

   ```
   $a = new BaseClass(["color"=>$color,"qwerty"=>$qwerty,...])
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Если вас реально интересует возможность управляться с динамическим количеством параметров, то можно использовать либо так:

```
class A 
{
    public function __construct(...$args)
    {
        switch (count($args)) {
            case 1:
                //use $args[0];
                break;
            case 2:
                //use $args[0], $args[1];
                break;
            case 3:
                //use $args[0], $args[1], $args[2];
                break;
        }
    }
}

$a = new A('color', 'qwerty', 'color');
```

, либо, как уже приводили пример, передавать параметры в массиве:

```
class B 
{
    public function __construct($args)
    {
        switch (count($args)) {
            case 1:
                //use $args[0];
                break;
            case 2:
                //use $args[0], $args[1];
                break;
            case 3:
                //use $args[0], $args[1], $args[2];
                break;
        }
    }
}

$b = new B(['123', '234']);

class C 
{
    public function __construct($args)
    {
        if (!emtpy($args['color'])) {
            if (!empty($args['qwerty'])) {
                if (!empty($args['name'])) {
                    //use [color, qwerty, name]
                } else {
                    //use [color, qwerty]
                }
            } else {
                //use only [color]
            }
        }
    }
}

$c = new C(['color' => '123', 'qwerty' => '234']);
```

, **либо, если вообще хотите динамические-прединамические, то как-то так**:

```
class D
{
    public function three($args)
    {
        print $args['color'].', '.$args['name'];
    }

    public function __construct($args)
    {
        $constructors = [
            'one' => ['color'],
            'two' => ['color', 'qwerty'],
            'three' => ['name', 'color'],
            'four' => ['color', 'qwerty', 'name']
        ];

        foreach ($constructors as $key => $value) {
            sort($constructors[$key]);
        }

        $keys = array_keys($args);
        sort($keys);

        $constructor = array_search($keys, $constructors);

        if ($constructor!==false) {
            $this->{$constructor}($args);
        } else {
            print 'not found';
        }
    }
}

$d = new D(['color' => 1, 'name' => 2]);
```

На мой взгляд, это самые верные решения.

Comment: @nika.brown09 я дополнил ответ классом D, теперь вообще динамика-прединамика :)